# Save MutableListOf<Checkbox> in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, save, restore

I have a problem and I don't know how I could create a function to save the state of a MutableListOf when the application is closed and another one to restore it when it is opened again. Could someone help me?

Code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
        val layout = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.layout)
        var numbers = 0
        var checkboxes = mutableListOf<CheckBox>()
        
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val checkbox = CheckBox(this)
            checkbox.text = text.text
            text.text = ""
            checkbox.textSize = 13f
            val font = Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.BOLD)
            checkbox.typeface = font
            layout.addView(checkbox)
            val params = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            params.setMargins(100, numbers * 75, 100, 100)
            params.width = 1020
            params.height = 120
            checkbox.layoutParams = params
            checkbox.id = View.generateViewId()
            val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
            constraintSet.clone(layout)
            constraintSet.connect(
                checkbox.id,
                ConstraintSet.TOP,
                layout.id,
                ConstraintSet.TOP,
                numbers * 75
            )
            constraintSet.connect(
                checkbox.id,
                ConstraintSet.START,
                layout.id,
                ConstraintSet.START,
                0
            )
            constraintSet.applyTo(layout)
            numbers += 1
            checkboxes.add(checkbox)
            checkbox.setOnClickListener {
                checkbox.animate().alpha(1f).withEndAction {
                    checkbox.isChecked = false
                    layout.removeView(checkbox)
                    numbers -= 1
                    checkboxes.remove(checkbox)
                    checkboxes.forEachIndexed { index, cb ->
                        val params = cb.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                        params.setMargins(0, index * 75, 0, 0)
                        cb.layoutParams = params
                        val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
                        constraintSet.clone(layout)
                        constraintSet.connect(
                            cb.id,
                            ConstraintSet.TOP,
                            layout.id,
                            ConstraintSet.TOP,
                            index * 75
                        )
                        constraintSet.applyTo(layout)
                    }
                }.start()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried many things but none of them have worked

Comment: "I have tried many things but none of them have worked" -- then please provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried and explain in detail what problems you encountered.

Comment: You can’t save and restore UI components, but you can store their *state*, which for a CheckBox is a Boolean. You can look at the official Android documentation for an explanation of the different options available to store and restore data, such as SharedPreferences, a database, or internal files.